# exec(ffmpeg) is not executing in php but will in terminal?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i have a website that allows users to upload videos and I have VPS server with ffmpeg installed, safe mode is off and have tested command in my terminal and it works however in php script when i try and run the command in exec() or even shell_exec() it does not execute. below is my code (changed some variables for privacy).

```
$video_name = $_FILES["post_vid"]["name"];
$Vurl = "/folder1/folder2/$vrand_file_name/$video_name";
$VnewName = $vrand_vid_name .".mp4";
$VurlNew = "/folder1/folder2/$vrand_file_name/$VnewName";
$convertold = "/home/user/directory/domain.com/$Vurl";
$convertNew = "/home/user/directory/domain.com/$VurlNew" ;
$ffmpegC = "/user/local/bin/ffmpeg";
exec($ffmpegC.' -y -i "'.$convertold.'" -f mp4 "'.$convertNew.'"');
```

I have the code just after a move_uploaded_file() which runs fine.
also checked and my php is using the same user as my terminal... 
any insight to this would be fantastic, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix your code near `exec` as follows, and Could you try?

```
$command = $ffmpegC.' -y -i "'.$convertold.'" -f mp4 "'.$convertNew.'" 2>&1';  
exec($command, $array);
var_dump($array);
exit;
```

By using `2>&1`, `stderror` is entered to `$array`.

So you can see the cause.

Good luck!

Comment: does not seem to make a difference... it is not creating the mp4 file as it did in terminal, and now with the `exit;` added it does not run the rest of the script, i tried moving it and just keep getting the same results.

Comment: ahhh yes sorry i had a mind blank... `array(1) {  [0]=> string(53) "sh: /user/local/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory"}`

Comment: What do you get when you run `$ which ffmpeg`.

Comment: Guessing that should be `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` instead of `/user/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: That is the cause. I did not notice either.

Comment: hmmm... i feel silly but it is `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` and upon closer looking at my other directories i amended and now it is all fixed! thanks @Yujiro ill comment the code after

Comment: `$video_name = $_FILES["post_vid"]["name"];
$Vurl = "folder1/folder2/$vrand_file_name/$video_name";
$VnewName = $vrand_vid_name .".mp4";
$VurlNew = "folder1/folder2/$vrand_file_name/$VnewName";
$convertold = "/home/user/directory/domain.com/$Vurl";
$convertNew = "/home/user/directory/domain.com/$VurlNew" ;
$ffmpegC = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
$command = ffmpegC.' -y -i "'.$convertold.'" -f mp4 "'.$convertNew.'"'; exec($command);`